# Synchronize two players playing the same m3u8 stream

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

Is there a way to synchronize two players playing the same m3u8 stream using AVFoundation?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I was looking for was to use two AVPlayerLayers and one AVPlayer - this is available from iOS6.

Comment: Even though the docs say you can not do this, it turns out you can.

Comment: how ? Seems like setRate:time:atHostTime: doesn't do anything with m3u8 playlists.